# Gremlin: removing duplicate values while using as()

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

This is my graph example:

[image]

The picture shows my example for graphdb, the question is: I wanted to get the suggestion friends for jetse ?

Here is the [vertices and edges creation for this example](https://github.com/Omaraqlan/CourseGraphDB)

I tried different queries. Sometimes I get column reference error, but I found a solution, but I'm sure its not optimal solution.

Starting Vertices: jetse
all vertices have property called: fname
edges: Works,KNOWS,Teaches,Enroll

what im trying to do is: 1- jetse works in itph, get people who work with jetse which STEF, people who know stef is Remsy, remsy teaches a course where there studendts.

the problem is when i output the result:
stef
remsey
Omar

stef
remsey
ufuk1

becuase they both have the vairables with them.

I want the result like

Stef Remsey Omar ufuk1 ufuk2

My solution is:

```
g.V('jetse').as('exclude').
  out('works').
  in().as('sug').
  where(neq('exclude')).
  in('knows').as('b').
  out('teaches').
  in('enroll').as('std').
  union(select('sug').by('fname'),
        select('b').by('fname'),
        select('std').by('fname')).
  dedup()
```

Do you have a better query for this solution ?

Comment: I do not see any steps to create the graph at the link you provided. Perhaps you could add those to the question to help people offer suggestions.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details sir, such as what kind of vertices can be recognized as the suggested friends. And upon your solution, I can't find edges like 'teach','know' etc.

Comment: sorry i uploaded a different drawing and uploaded the text file for creation. 
the problem while using as they hold the vairables, so when i want to use select(sug,b,std) it will throw error, but if i use select(std).values() it will output remsey and stef three times in each student. the edges is Teaches and KNOWS

Comment: I have no other ideas. Could u pls share your idea about why you wanna a 'better' query? Does your query meet some shortage or error?

Comment: im new to graphdb and i want to do multiple solutions to one question.

Comment: Don't worry sir, what you have is the best. You can post your query as the answer. Before others provide a better one, yours is always the best :).

Comment: thanks alot, sometimes i need a little push , anyways thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for tiny-wa for giving me confidence about my answer.

```
    g.V('jetse').as('exclude').
  out('works').
  in().as('sug').
  where(neq('exclude')).
  in('knows').as('b').
  out('teaches').
  in('enroll').as('std').
  union(select('sug').by('fname'),
        select('b').by('fname'),
        select('std').by('fname')).
  dedup()
```